# Convert all longer words from paragraph to links via jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink

I have a problem with some experimental idea. Probably only the jQuery Gurus can help me here  :)

I have a paragraph:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

And i need to **convert all the words with at least 4 characters "on-the-fly" onMouseOver with the help of jQuery to links created from each word**.

I don't want to generate it in HTML (because of bandwidth, it will grow to megs), that code will look like:

```
<p>
<a href="/search?q=Lorem">Lorem</a> 
<a href="/search?q=Ipsum">Ipsum</a> 
is 
<a href="/search?q=simply">simply</a>
.........
</p>
```

I will appreciate also any text-decoration onMouseOver.

Comment: I tried something with: $('#text > p').bind('mouseenter', callFunction); and .children() selector, but it did not worked.

Comment: And in case i cannot solve that i have to use this doubleclick demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/5D4d3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("p").on("hover", function(){
    var content = ​$("p").text();​​​​​
    var words = content.split(" ");
    var length = words.length;
    var newContent = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(words[i].length >= 4){
          newContent.push("<a href='/search?q=simply'>" + words[i] +"</a>")
         }else{
           newContent.push(words[i])
         }
    }     
    $(this).text("");
    $(this).html(newContent.join(" "));              
});
```

This will not, however, remove the `a` tags after you hover out and will run for every hover event. There are may fixes for both issues, but I will leave those to you to figure out.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N9WQt/)**

Comment: Great, i have modified it little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/N9WQt/2/
I can live without the text-decoration onMouseOver. 

It looks very understandable for me now. Thank you !

Comment: Glad it helped. If you need anything else then just let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this to your document.ready or document.load call:

```
$('p').on('hover', 'a', function(){ /* do whatever needs to be done on your link */});
var new_text = [];
$.each($('p').text().split(" "), function(index, word) {
    if (word.length >= 4) {
        word = word.replace(/(\w*)/, '<a href="YOUR URL HERE">\1</a>');
    }
    new_text.push(word);
});
var new_text_as_str = new_text.join(" ");
$('p').html(new_text_as_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this is, but:

```
​$('p').hover(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text();
    txt = txt.replace(/\b([a-z]{4,})\b/ig, '<a class="word" href="/search?q=$1">$1</a>');
    $(this).html(txt);
}, function(){
    $('a.word', this).each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

It adds links on `mouseenter` and removes them on `mouseleave`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8Yqfb/